# Load a form inside eclipse tableviewer

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, treeview, eclipse-rcp

I have been trying to implement to below table in eclipse RCP application using TableViewer, where if user click on any row it will load another form and display it right below to the row ,exactly same as below UI.

[image: Custom TableViewer]

Is it possible to tweak the eclipse tableviewer and display another form just like the above UI ? 
It looks like eclipse tableviewer work in accordance with the cell, so it has some limitation for displaying above UI. Please help me, i am new to the eclipse RCP application.

Comment: No you can't do this with `TableViewer`, the best you could manage would be a popup dialog using `DialogCellEditor`.

Comment: @greg-449 thanks for your answer. Going with the popup seems only relevant option. However, having a plugin for this kind of table will be nice.May be in my leisure time i will try to create one. But for now i will go with the popup.